# Create a Nuget package without adding that dependency to the current project?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, dependency-management

Using .NET Core, I'm trying to create a new Nuget without it installing the it's own dependencies.
This is my new NuGet package csproj:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <TargetFrameworks>net461</TargetFrameworks>
    <PackageId>MyFirstNuget</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.1-prerelease</Version>
    <Authors></Authors>
    <Company></Company>
    <Description></Description>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <SccLocalPath>.</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="7.12.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I install the package on a project it installs the package "SomePackage"
[image: example]

Is there an option not to install all the dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with PackageReference there are some ways to control dependency assets.

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets):

> IncludeAssets: These assets will be consumed
>
> ExcludeAssets: These assets will not be consumed
>
> PrivateAssets: These assets will be consumed but won't flow to the parent project

In your case you need to use PrivateAssets like this:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="7.12.4">
       <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

since your project uses SomePackage, but you don't want SomePackage installed when you use your new NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

I think [PrivateAssets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) can help you. Try changing your `PackageReference` to

```
<PackageReference Include="UmbracoCms" Version="7.12.4">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: It still installs all the files

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your original question very well. Do you want to remove UmbracoCms content from your project? Or do you want UmbracoCms to not be a dependency of your package, so when someone else installs your package, they do not get UmbracoCms?

Comment: I have project that include nuget like UmbracoCms when I do build I don't want to see the files (I don't want that install the UmbracoCms into the project that include the nugets) only when I install the *.nupkg file (example other project) I want to see the file for umbraco

Comment: ok, I think `<ExcludeAssets>content;contentFiles</ExcludeAssets>` is what you want, but I'm really sorry, I have trouble understanding your messages.